# Restarting the Application server(Jboss EAP 4.3) improves the performance?

Tags: performance, jboss

We are using the Jboss EAP 4.3 server for our Java Web Application. Is there any advantage of restarting the Application server on daily basis ?

Answer (score 0):

In production environment it is not recommended to restart server on daily basis. This might cause down time in production. Also you may lose some ongoing transactions if there is no configuration done for failover and load balancing.

You can restart server weekly or whenever there is slowness in processing request.